# Why answer questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

This is my second day on Stack Overflow (my current reputation is 72). Why should I answer questions on Stack Overflow? I have no problem helping people, but as I understand it, even if I earn 1,000,000 rep points, I won’t get any diploma or anything, so what should motivate me to answer questions here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: If you don't want to do it, no one is forcing you. Go do something else that brings you joy.

Comment: Personal enjoyment?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21037/addiction-towards-stack-overflow

Comment: To help yourself understand concepts by teaching people why things are the way they are? To give back to the community that helped you? Because you like internet points?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stack-overflow-are-you

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209582/what-is-reputation-useful-for-outside-of-stack-overflow

Comment: Don’t get me wrong, I just want to understand myself,

Comment: to gain rep & badges, and learning stuff as a little extra :)

Comment: Closed as duplicate... although, to be fair, the original question (and the answers posted there) are a joke.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question,

Comment: **Is changing my profile the Answer?**

Comment: @java-love We didn't change your profile, we migrated the question to the appropriate site, where you have different profile.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t recognize,

Comment: How do I switch between sites?

Comment: Use the collider up top-left.